# Detect if compositor is running

Tags: x11, xlib

I want my UI to change design depending on whether the screen is composited (thus supporting certain effects) or not. Is it possible to

- Reliably query whether the X server is running a compositing window manager
- Get notified when compositing is switched on/off?

**Solution:**

To elaborate on Andrey Sidorov's correct answer for people not so familiar with the X11 API, this is the code for detecting a EWMH-compliant compositor:

```c
int has_compositor(Display *dpy, int screen) {
    char prop_name[20];
    snprintf(prop_name, 20, "_NET_WM_CM_S%d", screen);
    Atom prop_atom = XInternAtom(dpy, prop_name, False);
    return XGetSelectionOwner(dpy, prop_atom) != None;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EWMH-compliant compositors [must acquire ownership of a selection named _NET_WM_CM_Sn, where n is the screen number](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472516176)

To track compositor you'll need to check if selection is `_NET_WM_CM_S0` is owned by anyone (assuming you are on screen 0) using `XGetSelectionOwner`. If not owned, acquire ownership yourself and monitor [SelectionClear](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#events:SelectionClear) events to detect when compositor is started.

Comment: Acquiring the ownership does not work, because e.g. picom does not start up if the selection is owned by another X client, because this looks as if another compositor is already running. (Also this does not work if multiple clients are waiting for the compositor to show up).