# QT using tranparent background on widget on Linux RHEL 7

Tags: c++, qt

I have seen several similar questions but I found none clear enough to the source of the problem. I am trying to have a widget that has a cornered border with a transparent background. It works fine on windows but on linux it has a black background.

I am using RHEL 7 and QT 5.7

Here is what I tried so far:

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

I read about ARGB and X server but I am not sure how to check them.

Comment: These flags and attributes are more like hints. It could be that Qt cannot achieve that on all systems.

Comment: @Trilarion How can I check if it is supported on the system that I'm using

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  Does your X11 display definitely have an active compositor (such as xcompmgr)?

Comment: @G.M. I am not quite familiar with the X Server display. Where can I check about the compositor

Comment: "How can I check if it is supported on the system that I'm using" I'm not sure. Maybe one could contact the makers of Qt and ask them. They should know more about it. At least they could tell you where these flags go and then you could dig deeper with the makers of the OS (RHEL in your case).

Comment: Re. `"Where can I check about the compositor"`.  If you have `xcompmgr` installed the simplest way to check would be to simply try running it from a terminal.  If there's already a composite manager running then `xcompmgr` will fail with a message such as `Another composite manager is already running (...)`.  Alternatively see[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195570/detect-if-compositor-is-running) but that's rather involved.